# nothing provides selinux-policy-base >= 3.14.3-80.el8_5.2

Tags: rhel, repository, dnf, snap

I am trying to install snap on my rhel 8.4 machine and it throws the following error

```
Error: 
 Problem: package snapd-2.54.1-1.el8.x86_64 requires snapd-selinux = 2.54.1-1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides selinux-policy-base >= 3.14.3-80.el8_5.2 needed by snapd-selinux-2.54.1-1.el8.noarch
```

I have selinux-policy-3.14.3-67.el8_4.2 on my machine.

Comment: Add the output of `subscription-manager repos --list` to the question.

Comment: I get "This system has no repositories available through subscriptions"

Comment: Add it to the question as well as the output of `subscription-manager status`. Do not post it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem is as described by the error:

> nothing provides `selinux-policy-base >= 3.14.3-80.el8_5.2`

Since none of your repos can provide this dependency, the installation cannot continue.

It seems that [similar issues](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/5940791) have happened before, and in that case the RHEL repos were simply lagging behind. You can try `sudo dnf upgrade --refresh` again and see if the package is now available. If not, I don't think there's a good solution to this issue without including third party repositories (which is likely not a good idea).

As you can see here: https://pkgs.org/download/selinux-policy-base

...version 3.14.3-80 is currently available both on AlmaLinux and Rocky Linux, which are binary compatible with RHEL. It seems strange that RHEL would not have the package considering they are upstream to both of them.

Perhaps you are using a satellite repo that is out of date with upstream? You should investigate your repos as the source of this error I think.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the rpm package on centos web site is good (https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-baseos-x86_64/selinux-policy-doc-3.14.3-80.el8_5.2.noarch.rpm.html), but the download link is broken (http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/selinux-policy-doc-3.14.3-80.el8_5.2.noarch.rpm)

I installed selinux-policy-base and dependencies using another repo with this command :

> yum install http://yum.stanford.edu/mrepo/centos8-x86_64/RPMS.os/selinux-policy-targeted-3.14.3-80.el8_5.2.noarch.rpm http://yum.stanford.edu/mrepo/centos8-x86_64/RPMS.os/selinux-policy-3.14.3-80.el8_5.2.noarch.rpm http://yum.stanford.edu/mrepo/centos8-x86_64/RPMS.os/selinux-policy-minimum-3.14.3-80.el8_5.2.noarch.rpm

Then you can install snapd :

> yum install snapd

Comment: im getting this error: [SSL certificate problem: certificate is not yet valid]